# How do I access an attribute of a "selected" element inline?

Tags: jquery

The following code doesn't work! 'this' in in the context when i access it is the document.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".myclass[id]").html(this.id);
});
```

How do I do the above without writing an extension or plugin? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to put an attribute value on the innerHTML each node on a set of matched elements.

I suggest you to [iterate](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/each) over all the matched elements, and get the attribute you desire of each one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".myclass[id]").each(function () {
    $(this).html(this.id);
    // or $(this).html($(this).attr('id'));
  });
});
```

Comment: **this** is different in the nested each function. **this** in the nested each anon function would be the iterated element, no longer the document.

Comment: @Kevin: Exactly, he wants an attribute value of the iterated elements.

Comment: Thanks this is a nice solution. I was doing it like this via  'jQuery.fn.extend({ ...' and then iteration over each. This is more code size efficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".myclass[id]").each(function(){
  //this is in the right context
});
```